# Need SQL Result set in below format

Tags: sql

I have table in below format

```
ID  TotalAmount AdjStatus
--------------------------
1   0           Approved
2   0           Closed
3   0           Disputed
```

I need the result set in multiple rows as below based on the column value AdjStatus.

```
ID  TotalAmount AdjStatus
---------------------------------
1   0           Approved
1   null        Closed
1   null        Disputed
2   0           Closed
2   null        Approved
2   null        Disputed
3   0           Disputed
3   null        Approved
3   null        Closed
```

Comment: Try to explain a bit more on why you want that, as well as why you cannot simply modify the content of your table. With the current information, it is quite difficult to understand, what you are actually trying to achieve...

Comment: @Noceo : I need to show the data in this way to the user. Instead on doing this in frontend, I want to manupulate from sql.

Comment: Please explain, in your question, in plain English the logic behind getting the expected result. This will help people reading this question, now and in the future, understand it better.

Comment: `ID` is the table's unique key, correct? There cannot be two records with the same `ID`?

Comment: What's the expected order if an ID has several non-null TotalAmount values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `CROSS JOIN` in the following:

```
select 
    t.Id, 
    case when t.AdjStatus <> t2.AdjStatus then null else t.TotalAmount end as TotalAmount,
    t2.AdjStatus
from #test as t
cross join #test t2
order by t.Id, case when t.AdjStatus <> t2.AdjStatus then null else t.TotalAmount end desc
```

You could test it at [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51181/1)

Comment: Or simply `order by t.Id, TotalAmount desc, t2.AdjStatus`.

Comment: This query only works, however, if not only the `ID` is unique in the table (as should be assumed from the name `ID`), but also the `AdjStatus` (which I wouldn't take for granted).